# Python: Share variable across processes

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have the following code which tries to share a counter variable across multiple processes. This counter variable is not getting updated in the readProcess module:

globals.py

```
import threading
lock = threading.Lock()

counter = 0
```

main.py:

```
from writeProcess import *
from readProcess import *

startRead()
startWrite()
```

readProcess.py:

```
import threading
import time

from globals import *
            
def readProcess():
    
    global counter
    print ("Counter (read):",hex(id(counter)))
    
    while True:
        
        with lock:
            print ("Counter (read):", counter)
        time.sleep(1)
        
def startRead():
    serverThread = threading.Thread(target=readProcess, args=())
    serverThread.start()
```

writeProcess:

```
import threading
import time

from globals import *

def writeProcess():
    global counter
    print ("Counter (write):",hex(id(counter)))
    while True:
        with lock:
            counter += 1
            print ("Counter (write):", counter)
        time.sleep(1)
            
def startWrite():
    serverThread = threading.Thread(target=writeProcess, args=())
    serverThread.start()
```

The output is:

```
Counter (read): 0x102eee910
Counter (read): 0
Counter (write): 0x102eee910
Counter (write): 1
Counter (write): 2
Counter (read): 0
Counter (read): 0
Counter (write): 3
Counter (write): 4
Counter (read): 0
Counter (write): 5
Counter (read): 0
Counter (write): 6
Counter (read): 0
```

Weirdly if I move the write stuff into the readProcess module it works. What am I missing?

Comment: See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html